# Click button is not working in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am new to angular world. I am in process of automating the angular 2 
application but I am having hard time to click a button.

Options tried:

1. I used various selectors like xpath, CSS, buttonText but none of them is working, s/m throws a timeout message or unable to find a selector.
2. When I try to print the element in console it is displaying as object object.
   Do I need to return the value in format of string and then attempt to click?
   Or
   Do I need to add any require plug in from NPM ? Please let me know

script snippet:

```
var resubmit=element.all(by.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent=''][text()='resubmit']")).get('0');
console.log("return"+resubmit);
resubmit.click();
```

Comment: did you try get(0)? or .first()

Comment: it returns a promise. You need to do a .then to get the text/value.

Comment: so this is not a complete answer, which is why I am putting it here. wrap that console.log as resubmit.getText().then(function(t){console.log ("return "+t);});

Comment: by.buttonText('resubmit') would seem most logical. Does that fail?

Comment: I tried get(0) and first (0 ), I resolved the promised and used buttonText, but all these options failed. Do i need to install any other dependencies for automating an angular 2 page ?

Comment: first() not first(0). But if it is not getting found at all, trying to get the first one or get the text is hopeless. Maybe try Selenium Builder to record yourself clicking on it, then at least for sure you get the locator right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait untill element is become clickable and then click. You do it by following:

```
EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var resubmit=element.all(by.buttonText('resubmit')).get('0');
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(resubmit), 15000,'Not Clickable'));
resubmit.click();
```

Comment: I tried the above but still i am not able to click the button. I noticed that application is quick and it loaded all buttons in the screen immediately.                  Error -
  Message:
    Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 110
 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. 
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: by.buttonText("resubmit")

Comment: If the page is not an angular app, you can put `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` at the beginning of your spec file that is testing that page. Or put it before that specific `it` that has the issue, and after that `it` put `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` (not sure if it would work this way, but worth trying).